# pip packages aren't accessible globally

Tags: python, path, pip

```
$ which pip                                                                                                                                                       Thu Dec 31 17:56:58 EST 2015
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ which python                                                                                                                                                        Thu Dec 31 18:01:09 EST 2015
/usr/local/bin/python
$ pip install flake8                                                                                                                                                  Thu Dec 31 18:01:20 EST 2015
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): flake8 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

...but when I try to run `flake8` it isn't recognized in my terminal as an executable.

It's like this with all my pip packages. None of them work globally.

What am I doing wrong? All this PATH crap confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add these new programs into your PATH. I'll operate under the assumption that you're using Linux.
In your ~/.profile file, you'll want to add in the following line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/PATH TO DIRECTORY OF EXECUTABLE
```

Note that this is not recursive.

In the case where your pip installations are all in some parent folder, I found a script that may make this easier.

```
for d in /usr/local/bin/*/; do
    PATH+=":$d"
done
```

This loops through some parent folder and adds each child folder into the path. :)

Comment: I thought that certain Python packages (like flake8) would automatically be added as global executables like with npm.

The loop doesn't work anyway because flake8 isn't in `/usr/local/bin/` but rather `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Comment: Oh I was just raising an example, you can change the path to reflect where flake8 is :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Fish Shell, but basically I had to add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/` to my `PATH`.

The command I used was `set PATH /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ $PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual environment by first installing the virtual environment by `sudo pip install virtualenv` and then creating one by `virtualenv myenv`. Then activate the environment by `source myenv/bin/activate`. Then your command prompt will change and include the name of the environment.

Once you are inside the environment, you can install your packages. The packages will be only available inside your environment. you can install your package by `sudo pip install flake8`. Once the installation process is finished, you can verify it by `pip freeze`. The output will include name of all the packages installed in that environment.

Once you want to stop using the environment, you deactivate it by typing `deactivate`

Comment: This doesn't make flake8 a global system executable. I want to be able to use flake8 from anywhere at any time, not just from within a virtualenv.